# Limit of the supremum of a continuous function over a varying set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

On a book I'm reading the author asserts that

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \max_{{\bar{Q}}_{T-\epsilon}} u = \max_{{\bar{Q}}_T} u$$

where ${\bar{Q}}_{T-\epsilon}$ is the closure of a varying spatial-temporal cylinder

$${Q}_{T-\epsilon} = \Omega \times (0, T-\epsilon)$$

$\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a domain and $u$ is a continuos function over the closure ${\bar{Q}}_{T}$.

Is this obvious? How to formally prove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll state this in greater generality, which I think makes the statement more transparent.

#### Claim

Let $A$ be a subset of topological space $X$, and let $f:A\to\mathbb R$ be a continuous function. If $A_1\subset A_2\subset $ is a sequence of subsets of $A$ such that $$A\subset \overline{\bigcup_n A_n}\tag{1} $$
then $$\sup_A f = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{A_n} f$$
(The supremum on the left may be infinite, in which case the limit is understood in the extended sense.)

#### Proof

Since the sequence $\sup_{A_n} f$ is increasing, we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{A_n} f=\sup_n \sup_{A_n} f \tag{2}$$
Since $A_n\subset A$ for every $n$, it follows that  $$\sup_A f \ge  \sup_n \sup_{A_n} f $$
To prove the reverse inequality, pick a sequence $x_n\in A$ such that $f(x_n)\to \sup_A f$. For each $n$ there is $r_n>0$ such that $f>f(x_n)-1/n$ in $r_n$-neighborhood of $x_n$. By assumption (1) this neighborhood contains a point $y_n$ in some set $A_{k_n}$. Since $f(y_n)\to \sup_A f$, it follows that
$$\sup_A f \le  \sup_n \sup_{A_n} f $$